# shutil.copystat() FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to use shutil.copystat() to copy a file. This is my code:

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

def main():
  if path.exists("textfile.txt"):
    src = path.realpath("textfile.txt")
    dest = src + ".bak"
    shutil.copystat(src, dest)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Development/Python/Exercise Files/Ch4/shell_start.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/x/Development/Python/Exercise Files/Ch4/shell_start.py", line 19, in main
    shutil.copystat(src, dest)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 375, in copystat
    lookup("utime")(dst, ns=(st.st_atime_ns, st.st_mtime_ns),
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have printed the paths and both are correct. My file structure is as follows:

```
/Ch4
    /shell_start.py
    /textfile.txt
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
shutil.copystat(src, dest)
```

by:

```
shutil.copy2(src, dest)
```

If you want to use `shutil.copystat`, do:

```
shutil.copy(src, dest)
shutil.copystat(src, dest)
```

Read the doc of [`shutil.copy2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2)

Answer (score 1):

**`shutil.copystat` doesn't copy files**, it only copies the status bits between two existing files.  What you want is `shutil.copy2`.

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, could you explain why .copystat() isn't working here?

Comment: Because your destination file does not exist.